# Validate user type and disable links few links in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code, but I want to disable few links on user type, in DB User, I have a user type, User and Admin, I need to verify after login if it's admin below all mentioned links should be enabled but if it's type is user, then Download and Rename links should be disabled. Please help me to verify this.

```
<style>
    .disable {
        position: relative;
    }
    .disable:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .disable a {
        color: gray;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>


<body>      
    <ul id="fileMenu" class="contextMenu">
        <li><a id ="addbtn" href="#add" >Add</a></li>
    <li class="download disable"><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
    <li class="download disable"><a href="#download">Rename</a></li>
        <li class="del"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
        <li class="copypath"><a href="#copypath">Copypath</a></li>

    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: while login into any account you need to set session for user type i.e. Admin or user. And then just check for the condition of user type login

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following...

```
<ul id="fileMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <?php if($_SESSION['is_admin']): ?><li><a id ="addbtn" href="#add" >Add</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['is_admin'] || $_SESSION['user']): ?><li class="download disable"><a href="#download">Download</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['is_admin'] || $_SESSION['user']): ?><li class="download disable"><a href="#download">Rename</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['is_admin']): ?><li class="del"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['is_admin']): ?><li class="copypath"><a href="#copypath">Copypath</a></li><?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

In your server-side login PHP .. you'll set $_SESSION['is_admin'] to true/false same with $_SESSION['user']

Comment: Victor thanks for your help but i am facing some problem while after login admin or user ... these links are disabled by default ... what i want is... when an admin logged in, then all these links should be enabled, and when user logged in, these 2 links will be disabled... would be grateful for your help ...

Comment: That's already correct.. you just have to set a default value for  $_SESSION['is_admin'] = false  and change to TRUE when admin is logged in.. same with the $_SESSION['user'] = false .... the code I have shared will hide the Links aside from Download and Rename if user is not admin which is the $_SESSION['user'] and will show all Links if user is Admin and that's  $_SESSION['is_admin']...

Comment: Victor, thanks for sharing it, quite easy and helpful but i was making some mistake... i got the desired value or output ... love it.